# Unexplained NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, jdbc

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate
>           at com.citi.cate.svn.eers.SVNEERSFeeder.loadEmpInfoFromDB(SVNEERSFeeder.java:117)
>           at com.citi.cate.svn.eers.SVNEERSFeeder.process(SVNEERSFeeder.java:523)
>           at com.citi.cate.svn.eers.SVNEERSFeeder.main(SVNEERSFeeder.java:631)
>           at resources.TheApp.main(TheApp.java:39) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 4 more

I am unable to find the solution for the above error. lately there was change in the spring-framework version and i changed all the jars related to the new version of spring-framework. i see the above error. tried to reload all the jars.still the error exists. please help me on this.

```
SVNEERSFeeder.java

line 117: JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(_utility.getDBConnection("csi", ""))
```

Comment: Where is the code producing the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is caused due to **misconfiguration of appropriate spring jdbc jars** related to the spring version. To resolve dependencies easily, you could use maven:
For example, if you are using **spring 4.2.5**, add s**pring jdbc dependencies** in maven as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Apache Ivy Dependencies:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="4.2.5.RELEASE"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. can you also let me know what is the solution in case I am using ANT?

Comment: So, Are you using Apache Ivy for  dependency management with Apache Ant?